# Disable autofill password in chromium

Tags: autocomplete, arguments, field, chromium, autofill

I would like to know if is possible to disable the autofill into my application using chromium.

[View example of autofill fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeyuU.jpg)

Currently, I'm using arguments:

```
--disable-popup-blocking --disable-infobars --disable-tab-switcher --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-restore-background-contents --disable-new-tab-first-run --disable-restore-session-state -overscroll-history-navigation=0 --enable-remote-extensions --system-developer-mode --noerrdialogs --disable-translate --remote-debugging-port=8081 --allow-insecure-localhost --ignore-certificate-errors
```

I tried these arguments :

```
--disable-single-click-autofill
--ignore-autocomplete-off-autofill
--disable-password-generation
--disable-password-generation
--password-store --> none
```

I also tried to add attributes into login and password input fields :

```
autocomplete --> none, off, new-password, address-level4
```

Thank you !